# PHP Atlas.ORM returns always the same result

Tags: php, orm, atlas

I want to load data from a SQLite database in PHP using Atlas.Orm.

When I run the following snippet, I get a set of 1773 results, but each result is the same!

```
$atlas = Atlas::new('sqlite:[Path To Database]');
$result = $atlas->select(Stop::class)->fetchRecords();
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of desperation, I found the issue by myself. The ORM needs the PRIMARY_KEY constant in the corresponding *Table class to be set, otherwise fetching records will fail like this.